# Django D3 reading csv data from mongodb to plot graph

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, csv, d3.js

I am trying to read csv data from mongodb to plot the graph,basically the code to get csv file is in the view.py (it's working), but at the moment i want to get the csv data to plot the graph. I have tried ways to get the data (one of it is ajax) to get the data from the link but failed.Below are the code and screenshot for the output.

**html code**

```
//.... 
  var dataset 
  d3.csv("{% url 'system:data' %}", type, function(error, data){
  if (error) throw error;
  dataset = data
  initialDomain = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Timestamp; });
  x.domain(initialDomain);
  ydomain = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d['AGV Mileage']; });
  y.domain(ydomain);
  x2.domain(x.domain());
  y2.domain(y.domain());
//....
```

**js**

```
 /*var csvData;
        $(document).ready(function() {
                csvData = $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://..../system/diagnostics/data",
                    dataType: "text/csv",
                    success: function (result) {
                       alert(result);
                       alert(result.getAllResponseHeaders())
                     }
                });
        })*/
```

**view.py**

```
//...
class DataView(DiagnosticMixin, TemplateView):

    def render_to_response(self, request):
        results = []
        end = timezone.now()
        start = end - timezone.timedelta(seconds=86400)

        cursor = get_database().Diagnostic.find({
            'timestamp': {
                '$gte': start,
                '$lt': end
            },
        }).sort('timestamp')

        first = True
        for doc in cursor:
            if first:
                keys = ['Timestamp']
                for st in doc['status']:
                    for kv in st['values']:
                        keys.append(kv['key'])
                if len(keys) < 240:
                    continue
                results.append('"%s"\n' % '","'.join(keys))
                first = False

            values = [timezone.make_naive(doc['timestamp'])]
            for st in doc['status']:
                for kv in st['values']:
                    values.append(kv['value'])
            results.append('"%s"\n' % '","'.join(['%s' % v for v in values]))

        return StreamingHttpResponse(results, content_type='text/csv')
```

**url.py**

```
//...
    url(r'^diagnostics/data$', DataView.as_view(), name='data'),
```

The page for the html is attached here[image: html]

The page for the html after added data word(.../system/diagnostic/data) to the link is attached here[image]

basically the csv is there,I have tried ways to get data from it but failed to get it and i am totally lost now.

Please enlighten me on this, thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
the csv data is successfully loaded, but there is one more issue when the variable csvData is put inside the d3.csv(), the error appeared and the graph wont be appearing [image: error]

```
the code :

 var global_csvData;
            $(document).ready(function() {
                   var csvData = $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "http://../system/diagnostics/data",
                        success: function (result) {
                          console.log(result);
                          console.log(csvData.getAllResponseHeaders());
                          global_csvData = csvData;
                         }
                    });
            })

       var csvData = global_csvData;
      d3.csv(csvData, type, function(error, data) {\\....}
```

for the length error i have tried to declare the variable global_csv variable but the outcome is still the same.

Comment: Can you put your js where your trying to call csv file

Comment: sorry, just now my js in the html code but now i separated it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your js as follows

```
 var csvData;
        $(document).ready(function() {
                csvData = $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://..../system/diagnostics/data",
                    success: function (result) {
                      console.log(result);
                      console.log(csvData.getAllResponseHeaders());
                     }
                });
        })
```

Remove `dataType` attribute from your ajax then it will work.
or change `dateType='text/csv'` to `dataType:'text'` because ajax function doesnt understand  dateType='text/csv' hence instead off `success` function it calls `error` function

Sample-Spreadsheet-10-rows.csv

```
1,"Eldon Base for stackable storage shelf, platinum",Muhammed MacIntyre,3,-213.25,38.94,35,Nunavut,Storage & Organization,0.8
2,"1.7 Cubic Foot Compact ""Cube"" Office Refrigerators",Barry French,293,457.81,208.16,68.02,Nunavut,Appliances,0.58
3,"Cardinal Slant-D� Ring Binder, Heavy Gauge Vinyl",Barry French,293,46.71,8.69,2.99,Nunavut,Binders and Binder Accessories,0.39
4,R380,Clay Rozendal,483,1198.97,195.99,3.99,Nunavut,Telephones and Communication,0.58
5,Holmes HEPA Air Purifier,Carlos Soltero,515,30.94,21.78,5.94,Nunavut,Appliances,0.5
6,G.E. Longer-Life Indoor Recessed Floodlight Bulbs,Carlos Soltero,515,4.43,6.64,4.95,Nunavut,Office Furnishings,0.37
7,"Angle-D Binders with Locking Rings, Label Holders",Carl Jackson,613,-54.04,7.3,7.72,Nunavut,Binders and Binder Accessories,0.38
8,"SAFCO Mobile Desk Side File, Wire Frame",Carl Jackson,613,127.70,42.76,6.22,Nunavut,Storage & Organization,
9,"SAFCO Commercial Wire Shelving, Black",Monica Federle,643,-695.26,138.14,35,Nunavut,Storage & Organization,
10,Xerox 198,Dorothy Badders,678,-226.36,4.98,8.33,Nunavut,Paper,0.38
```

Test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var x = $.ajax({
                     url:"Sample-Spreadsheet-10-rows.csv",type:"GET",
                     dataType:"text",
                     success:function(result){
                          console.log("success");
                          console.log(x.responseText);
                       },
        error:function(result){
                          console.log(x.responseText)
                      }
       });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Get RESPONSE TEXT</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your swift response, the csv data is displayed on the console log, sorry for bothering you again, but there is 1 issue, when i put the variable csvData into d3.csv(), errors appeared in the console log

Comment: try `csvData.responseText` that will give you response text.

Comment: ahh..i replaced csvData.getAllResponseHeaders() with csvData.responseText, but still the same output.

Comment: If you are loading from csv file into d3 using `d3.csv()`  please use as follows `d3.csv("/http://..../system/diagnostics/data", function(data) {console.log(data[0]);});` http://learnjsdata.com/read_data.html docs for more info